# Amazon VPC/NAT connectivity issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up NAT on a windows server 2008 r2 instance inside a VPC on AWS.

I've got two windows boxes, `A` and `B`

`A` has two network interfaces, one with an EIP attached and can connect to the internet fine.

`B` has its `default gateway` set to the private IP of `A`s 2nd NIC (configured in RRAS as the private NIC)

All NICs are in a security group with all ports open.

I can RDP on to `A`, and from `A` to `B`, but `A` and `B` can't ping each other, and `B` can't route any traffic through `A`.

Tracerts timeout on every hop (they dont even hit `B`)

Any idea whats going wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable source/dest check on `A`'s 2nd interface.

Docs only say to do it on the instance. grrr

Comment: I set up the NAT instance, but I can't ping instances inside my public or my private subnets. How did you disable source/dest on 2nd interface?